# ESC signal standard and PWM frequency

Tags: arduino, pwm, motor-controller

I got the following code from [the video](https://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/arduino-brushless-motor-control-tutorial-esc-bldc/). However, I encountered an issue that, the motor tended to stop working at maximum value.

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo ESC;     // create servo object to control the ESC
int potValue;  // value from the analog pin

void setup() {
  ESC.attach(9,100,2000); // (pin, min pulse width, max pulse width in microseconds) 
  ESC.writeMicroseconds(1000);

}


void loop() {

potValue = analogRead(A0);  
potValue = map(potValue, 0, 1023, 1000, 2000);   
ESC.writeMicroseconds(potValue);
}
```

The ESC I used was BL Heli ESC. This issue appear to be some what general. Is there any particular reason to stop ESC and motor operating at 100%?

Question part 2: The webpage and online resource usually said "The ESC accept pulse from 1 ms and 2 ms." and "... operated at 50 Hz"(every 20ms), which represented the operation from 0% to 100%.

2a. Can we send 5V constant signal to ESC? Does it represent 100% operation?

2b. What if we send 1.5/2 ms for every 10ms signal to ESC? Does that represent 50%, or some value between 25% to 50%?

Answer (score 4):

You made a few errors in your code:

`ESC.attach(9,100,2000);` should be `ESC.attach(9,1000,2000);`, so, **1000** instead of 100.

and

`potValue = map(potValue, 0, 1023, 1000, 2000);` should be `potValue = map(potValue, 0, 1023, 0, 180);`
because the next line, the command  `writeMicroseconds(angle)` only accepts a value to write to the servo, **from 0 to 180**

Have a look how servo control works:

[image]

> 2b. What if we send 1.5/2 ms for every 10ms signal to ESC? Does that represent 50%, or some value between 25% to 50%? Does it represent 100% operation?

You should send a pulse each **20** ms, because that is how (this) servo signal/BLDC motor control signal is defined. You cannot change that to 10 ms.
For your convenience:

```
  0 degrees corresponds a pulse witdh of 1.00 ms corresponds to   0% of max RPM*
 45 degrees corresponds a pulse witdh of 1.25 ms corresponds to  25% of max RPM
 90 degrees corresponds a pulse witdh of 1.50 ms corresponds to  50% of max RPM
135 degrees corresponds a pulse witdh of 1.75 ms corresponds to  75% of max RPM
180 degrees corresponds a pulse witdh of 2.00 ms corresponds to 100% of max RPM

*or 1% (I'm not sure how it is implemented)
```

> 2a. Can we send 5V constant signal to ESC?

This pulse width should be between 1 ms and 2 ms. A pulsed signal is not a constant signal, so, no, you cannot send a 5V constant signal.
That's also the reason the min and max values of `ESC.attach(9,1000,2000);` should be 1000 resp. 2000.

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ServoWriteMicroseconds It seemed to indicate that it can accept value below 1000 at least until 700.

Comment: The next line of your quoted line is: *Note that some manufactures **do not follow** this **standard** very closely so that servos often respond to values between 700 and 2300* The command is to also cover non-standard servo control. The website/video you were refering to is quite clear it should between 1000us and 2000us.

Comment: Good job Huisman.  >shout... the implmentation differences between target devices might react differently when going beyond stds. Although a wider PW50 or pulse width might translate into finer resolution for some servos , it might have be detected as noise or have no effect on others.

Comment: Shouldn't the function be ESC.write(), not ESC.writeMicroseconds() if you're passing an angle? (0 to 180 per your answer) That would match the documentation.