# Controlling BLDC motor using Arduino and esc

Tags: motor, pwm, frequency, brushless-dc-motor

[Reffering to this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/474764/esc-signal-standard-and-pwm-frequency#new-answer?newreg=c0d25ea1c5f0446fa212e13428f8e125)

Do all ESCs operate on this 1ms to 2ms range and 50Hz PWM or is this different for different ESCs, for example, one ESC for RC drones and another ESC for 5055 200kv BLDC motor for electric skateboards.

Comment: Please include enough detail in the question itself and ask a specific question so that potential respondents don't have to go to off-page resources. Thanks.

Comment: All? Probably not. But it's a pretty common standard.